# Higher order function name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, higher-order-functions

I've just wrote this function for answer on SO:

```js
function ngWrap($scope, fn) {
    return function() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        return $scope.$apply(function() {
            fn.apply(null, args);
        });
    };
}
```

With a better version:

```js
function ngWrap($scope, fn) {
    return function() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        if ($scope.$$phase) {
            fn.apply(null, args);
        } else {
            return $scope.$apply(function() {
                fn.apply(null, args);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

that can be use to shorten this:

```js
socket.on('myevent', function(arg){$scope.$apply(function(){trigger_fn(arg)})})
```

into:

```js
socket.on('myevent', ngWrap($scope, trigger_fn));
```

Does this function have a name (the first one) or maybe you can write simple version of it using underscore (that can use just `$scope.$apply.bind($scope)` as argument) or maybe lisp have a function that word that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this function have a name

Not that I know, but I could think of "lifting `fn` to the Angular `$scope`" or so.

> you can write simple version of it using underscore

Yes, what you're doing there is basic function composition, so you can use Underscore's [`compose` function](http://underscorejs.org/#compose):

```
function ngWrap($scope, fn) {
    return _.compose($scope.$apply.bind($scope), fn);
}
```